# How to add Wiris plugin to CKEditor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I am having a Rails application with CKEditor integration.

I was no able to integrate the Wiris plugin into it

My `config.js` looks like this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'others' },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'about' }
    ];

    config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

    config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

    config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
};
```

I have downloaded the Wiris plugin from [here](http://www.wiris.com/en/plugins3/ckeditor/download) and copied it to `app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins`

I tried adding this in `config.js` file:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.extraPlugins += (config.extraPlugins.length == 0 ? '' : ',') + 'ckeditor_wiris';
    config.toolbar_Full.push({ name: 'wiris', 
    items : [ 'ckeditor_wiris_formulaEditor', 'ckeditor_wiris_CAS' ]});
};
```

But nothing seems to be working.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: We are currently working on a Ruby on Rails specific plugin, it will be available in a few weeks. We will post here again to let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WIRIS is now available for Ruby on Rails! You can see the CKeditor demo at http://www.wiris.com/plugins/demo/ckeditor/ruby/. You will find the links to the download and documentation on the demo page. 
Our Ruby on Rails plugin is also available for TinyMCE and for generic HTML editors.

Comment: Is that editor for php or ruby,here you are mentioned ruby but after click that url its redirecting to php.

Comment: You can download the Ruby plugin from: http://www.wiris.com/en/plugins/ckeditor/download. You can also download the demo from: http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/demo-download.

Comment: I'm getting this error : -                   


ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/generic_wiris/tests/generic_demo.html"):

Comment: This may be a specific issue of your installation, we believe it would be better to follow-up via e-mail, please provide us more details at support@wiris.com.